# Javascript Regexp test method weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying evaluate a string based in a regular expression, however I noticed a weird behaviour and when I test with the regular expression more than once. The test method alternates between true and false .
Check this codepen --> http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/BoXrEz?editors=001

```
var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]){0,100}\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]){0,100}\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/,
  phoneChileanRegex = /^\+56\S*\s*9\S*\s*\d{8}(?!\@\w+)/g,
   number = "+56982249953";

if(!number.match(phoneChileanRegex)  && !number.match(emailRegex) ) {
  console.log("it's not a phone number or email address");
}

//Weird Behaviour
console.log(phoneChileanRegex.test(number)); --> true
console.log(phoneChileanRegex.test(number)); --> false
```

Comment: That is happening because of `g` flag, Check [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxKbye?editors=001)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> As with `exec()` (or in combination with it), `test()` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

So, the second time you call the method, it will look for a match after the first match, i.e. after `+56982249953`. There is no match because the pattern is anchored to the start of the string (`^`) (and because there are no characters left), so it returns `false`.

To make this work you have to remove the `g` modifier.

Answer (score 7):

That's because the `test` method, like many `RegExp` methods, tries to find multiple matches in the same string when used with the `g` flag. To do this, it keeps track of position it should search from in the RegExp's `lastIndex` property. If you don't need to find multiple matches, just don't put the `g` flag. And if you ever want to use it, just remember to set `regex.lastIndex` to 0 when you want to test a new string.

[Read more about `lastIndex` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

Comment: Exactly apt answer. I found out by placing a breakpoint after 1st console.log and inspecting `phoneChileanRegex.lastIndex` and it showed 12, which means it was tracking the position due to `g` flag

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand what's happened when i use the `.test` method. Generally I use the `g` flag when I use the  `String.replace` method and I dont knew about this behaviour in the `Regexp.test` method.