# RegEx false negative with .test()

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a Chrome extension that searches a page for a dollar amount (a number with no more then two decimal places immediately preceded by a "$") then tacks on a bit with how much that value would be in another currency. I found a commonly used regex that matches exactly those parameters.

```
/^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$/g
```

so I'm thinking I have a nice headstart. I've only been coding a couple of months and of all the concepts I've encountered, regex's give me the most headache. I test out my shiny new expression with:

```
var regex = /^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$/g;

var str = "The total it $2.25 Would you like paper or plastic?";

r = regex.test(str);
console.log(r);
```

and of course that sucker returns false! I tried a few more strings with "2.25" or "$2" or "$2.256" just to be sure and they all returned false.

I am thoroughly stumped. The expression came recommended, I'm using .test() correctly. All I can think of is it's probably some small newbish detail that has nothing to do with regex's.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: That regex looks like it matches at the start of the string, so it would only match if you tested it on ONLY a dollar value (without the rest of the string). My regex-fu isn't strong enough to fix that, but that's somewhere to start (the `^` at the start of the regex matches the start of the string).

Comment: Hint, it's the `^` --> https://regex101.com/r/cA1tE9/1

Comment: The `$` at the end of the regex is also a problem

Comment: Well, the last `$2.256` [is not matched](https://regex101.com/r/qW3sT8/1). Not sure it is [that dupe I chose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034770/javascript-regexp-test-method-weird-behaviour). At any rate, you must remove the `/g` flag if you want to use the regex with `RegExp#test()`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is a valid duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overly complex regular expression is checking the entire string. Remove the `^` and `$` which denote the beginning and end of the string, respectively. Then remove the `/g` flag, which is used to search for multiple matches.

What's wrong with [checking for `/\$\d+\.\d\d/`](https://regex101.com/r/nX5qH9/1)?

I find http://regex101.com/ to be a helpful resource.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the ^ and \$ were combined and  it meant "start looking for everything else that begins with a $". I didn't even see that last $. I just discovered regex101 today while working on this problem. I'll have to spend some serious time with it.

Comment: One thing though. Your expression workswonderfully for sites like amazon but if someone just posts "$35" with no cents it still returns false which is enough to get started but I'll have to work something out later.

Comment: `/\$\d+(?:\.\d\d)?/` makes the decimal portion optional