# Why do these seemingly similar props result in different behavior?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

**Question:**

- Why does my WarningMessage component render differently when I pass `testFor="custom"` instead of "a" or "b" even though my console.log statements seem to suggest it's working identically.
- I'm especially confused because the console.log statement in renderMessageStyle() suggests it's working correctly in all scenarios (see bottom for example)

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/q4m8mq

**Expected behavior:**

When I type "c" into the input field it, the warning message should appear after a single keystroke. For an example of proper behavior change testFor="a" in Parent and type "a" into the input field.

**How it works:**

- In the Parent component I give a string value to the `testFor` prop.
- The testFor prop is passed to the WarningMessage component which uses its value in `testForX()` to return the proper regex formula.
- The result is saved to a variable called regEx which acts as a gatekeeper for whether to display the message by running `{regEx.test(testWatch) && renderMessageStyle(messageType, message)}`

Other notes:

- testForX can accept the strings "a", "b", or "custom"
- If "custom" is passed then `testForX()` sets its return value to the `regFormula` prop passed from Parent. The `regFormula` prop is not used otherwise.
- I'm using [useWatch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch) from react-hook-form to monitor input field changes

Display a warning message when a user's input meets certain regex tests when I pass one-off "custom" regex as a prop to the child WarningMessage component.

**Example:**

```
const renderMessageStyle = (messageType, message) => {

    // This console statement works for all cases but the switch statement isn't displaying properly

    console.log("renderMessageStyle fired!", testWatch, testFor, regEx);

    switch (messageType) {
      case "warn":
        return (
          <span className="text-sm font-bold text-amber-600 pt-4 pb-2">
            ⚠️ This is a warning message for what you wrote in the input field:{message}
            {message}
          </span>
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `RegExp.prototype.test` [advances through the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034770/javascript-regexp-test-method-weird-behaviour)

When you pass it from the parent your `testForX` is called only once so the regexp is used multiple times. If you don't pass it from the parent, you create a new regexp every time a key is pressed.

It's better to just use `String.prototype.match` instead as it gives every time the same results.